# Legal issues upon capturing digital proof upon hosting services scam

Tags: discussion, support

Is ServerFault the wrong place to ask for advice of ...

> how should someone register/capture digital scam proof to be legally
>   sustainable and enough for building a case with a Consumer Protection
>   Agency or even to take it to the court

... about a matter upon a very probable scam from a hosting company?

The related question was this one: [Nonexistent domain folder reappears with malware](https://serverfault.com/questions/836691/nonexistent-domain-folder-reappears-with-malware?noredirect=1#comment1069623_836691)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes... it is the wrong place... How is it that you think the SF community could assist or advise you on what you think is a legal matter? Even if any of us had an inkling about the legal machinations involved, our input would be anecdotal and non-authoritative and it would be unwise for anyone to heed such. If you really feel this is a legal matter then your best course of action would be to seek the council of an attorney who specializes in this area.

Answer (score 11):

You've had this thoroughly explained to you already, but just to reiterate:

Among other things Server Fault is *not* for:

- End user technical support
- Mass web hosting questions
- Legal questions

Given the nature of your question, what you actually need is a *lawyer*. One who is in a law firm that has experience in this sort of thing. Unfortunately that is absolutely the best advice you will get anywhere on the Internet.